# how to change css of the image link when clicked?

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a commandLink that has a graphicImage inside and i want to change some property
of the link to show that it is clicked.I could find no built-in property for that purpose.
Maybe some javascript or css code is required.Since i am not so good at those,i'd be glad if someone could guide me a way.Thanks

Here is the code of the link.

```
                    <p:commandLink title="Forward" update="growl"
                        actionListener="#{roombaBean.forward}">
                        <p:graphicImage value="images/but_forward.png" />
                    </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onclick event of the commandLink to execute javascript. 
Something like

```
<p:commandLink onclick="changeCSSInJavascript()" ...> 
.... 
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: ok,we can change the css using on.. attributes as follows: onclick="this.className='ctlBtn btnDown'".

Answer (score 0):

You could add a style attribute to primefaces graphicImage and give it a string value from a bean. After the link it's clicked you could update that string value with: `opacity:0.4`:

```
<p:commandLink title="Forward" update="growl"
                        actionListener="#{roombaBean.forward}">
  <p:graphicImage value="images/but_forward.png" style="#{myBean.myStringStyleValue}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

For IE8 and earlier use `filter:alpha(opacity=40);`

Anyway I don't really understand why do you want something like this? Don't you navigate away from the page? Why is it really matter that the image was clicked? Please, if you could give some more info, we could see if there is a better solution...

Comment: i don't navigate to another page,the link is used to control a device(in meaning go forward)..nothing happens on the page when the link is clicked so user may be in doubt about whether clicking the link really worked or not.thats why i want to change some stuff about the link while clicking process.

Comment: @sogukk You could try the opacity solution or you could show a primefaces message or growl dynamically where you inform the user that the link has been clicked/processed. Tell me if you'd want an example of how a growl can be implemented...